# What is difference about [] and <> that in aws cli help message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, notation

I enter this command:

```
aws help
```

Then I saw this line:

```
aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [parameters]
```

I know all of [] and <> are represent about let me type some words replace it. But what is the difference between [] and <>?

Comment: Optional (`[]`) vs. required (`<>`).

Comment: There's also an element of plural vs. singular here. You may specify 0 or more options and 0 or more parameters (depending on the awscli command/subcommand), but you must specify exactly one command and one subcommand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments in angular brackets (`<>`) ae required, arguments in square brackets (`[]`) are optional. E.g., you have to have a command and a subcommand, but options are, well, optional.